# Symmetric matrix with $a_{ij} = 0$ for all $|i - j| > 1$ has all eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1 . Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix such that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ for $|i-j|>1$. Moreover $a_{ij}$ is non-zero for all $i$,$j$ satisfying $|i-j| = 1$. Show that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are of multiplicity $1$.
>
> 2 . Give examples of 2 real $n \times n$ matrices  $X = (x_{ij})$, $Y = (y_{ij})$ where $x_{ij} = x_{ji}$ and $y_{ij} = y_{ji}$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ so that $xX +yY$ has $n$ non-repeated eigenvalues for all real numbers $x$, $y$ where $x$, $y$ are not zero simultaneously.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: for part(2), let X = diag(1,2,0,3) and Y = diag(4,0,5,6).

Comment: @Inquest What if x=y=1?

Comment: In part 1. you have the Jacobi matrices. This property is well-known.

Comment: @Timothy. Argh. You are right. Ignore my comment.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with the second one ?

Answer (score 1):

2) Let $X,Y$ be linear independent real symmetric matrices of order 2 and trace zero.

Let $Z$ be any linear combination of X and Y. Notice that $Z$ has the same properties. Therefore its eigenvalues $(Z$ is diagonalizable since it is real symmetric$)$ have oppositive signs $($their sum must be zero$)$, unless $Z$ is the zero matrix.
But it occurs only if $Z$ is the trivial combination of $X$ and $Y$.

Now for matrices of order $2k$ $(2k+1)$, instead of $X$ and $Y$, use $F(X)$ and $F(Y)$ $(G(X)$ and $G(Y))$.

$F(X)=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
X & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 
0 & 2X & \dots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & kX
\end{array} \right)_{2k\times2k}$ $G(X)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
F(X) & 0_{2k\times 1} \\ 
0_{1\times 2k} &  0_{1\times 1}
\end{array} \right)_{2k+1\times 2k+1}$

If $Z$ is any linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ then $F(Z)$ $(G(Z))$ is be the respective linear combination of $F(X)$ and $F(Y)$ $(G(X)$ and $G(Y))$.

If $a,-a$ are the eigenvalues of $Z$ then $a,-a,2a,-2a,\dots,ka,-ka$ are the eigenvalues of $F(Z)$ $(a,-a,2a,-2a,\dots,ka,-ka,0$ are the eingevalues of $G(Z))$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.*

1. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. As $A$ is diagonalisable, can you relate the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ to the rank of $\lambda I-A$? Now, let $B$ be the submatrix obtained by deleting the *first* row and *last* column of $\lambda I-A$. What is the rank of $B$? Then, what is the rank of $\lambda I-A$?
2. Split a matrix in the form of $A$ in part 1 into two appropriate symmetric matrices!